# Blog Post Title isn't showing up on shared link

Tags: hyperlink, blogger, sharing

Whenever I share a link of any of my blog posts, the shared link shows the blog title instead of Post title, in facebook as well as Google+.

[Link to blog](http://ravitejajnv.blogspot.com)

As shown in the image below; confused.me, is the title of the blog not the post.

[Link to image](https://copy.com/zUGbxc63jGxtq91H)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement OpenGraph meta tags in your blog.
refer this link which describe you how to implement opengraph meta tags in blogspot

http://blogger-hints-and-tips.blogspot.in/2013/06/add-facebook-open-graph-tags-to-blogger-for-better-looking-shares-and-likes.html